# Upvoting but not accepting an answer

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I recently asked a question and someone gave an answer that did not solve my problem, but provided useful information about it. I upvoted it but did not accept it as the answer because I still have the issue.

So my question is - When I upvote the answer does this make the question show up as answered? Does it make my question less likely for other people to see it?

The reason I ask is because I got views on my question and an answer shortly after posting it. I upvoted the answer but since then, I haven't gotten another and barely have gotten any views on it. I even set a bounty on it and still no answers and hardly any views, which does not seem normal.

Comment: No, the question doesn't appear as answered until you *accept* an answer.

Comment: ^^Clarification - it will show as having one answer (and a green block) but not as being accepted (yellow text in green block) when listed among other questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I upvote the answer does this make the question show up as answered?

Not quite. There is a distinction between *questions without answers* and *questions with an accepted answer* that comes down to some yellow text in the answer count.

The answer count indicates the three states of a question

- **No green block** - A question without answers.
- **Green block with white text** - A question without an accepted answer.
- **Green block with yellow text** - A question with an accepted answer.

Upvoting and accepting answers are two distinctly different actions. You can upvote any answer you want, sometimes that will be the case on your questions, but you can only accept one. Questions without accepted answers will still display in the unanswered questions list, most likely to prevent people from adding unhelpful answers and knocking them off of the list.

In order to accept an answer you must select the green check mark that is visible next to the answer.

> Does it make my question less likely for other people to see it?

Not as far as I know. Though keep in mind that some people will only seek out questions without answers, so having an answer (even if not accepted) can limit the visibility. There isn't too much you can do about this, some people just seek out those valuable imaginary internet points.

> I even set a bounty on it and still no answers and hardly any views which does not seem normal.

Unfortunately on Stack Overflow, there can be hundreds of questions with active bounties at a time. Again, your issue most likely has to do with having an existing answer.

> someone gave an answer that did not solve my problem

Important side note: Did you tell them that it did not solve your problem? They might be willing to help, but they won't know unless you tell them.

Comment: I commented telling them that I tried their solution and it did not work, although it did give me clues on what the problem actually is.
When I respond to an answer, do I have to tag their name or anything in order for them to see the I responded? Because the person never commented back

Comment: Nope, any comments on your own answers will notify you, so they don't need to be pinged. Some people don't reply to comments, but usually if you get them time you can get a response.

Comment: @Frobot _"Because the person never commented back "_ Don't worry, that's a common case. If you found a solution yourself, you always can put another answer. If you upvote an answer that helped you in the way, there's nothing wrong with it. Just think of it honouring the author's efforts put in.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's perfectly OK to accept an answer that doesn't solve your problem if it provides you with a useful way forward. That might include, for example, telling you that the problem is insoluble (and why), telling you how to gather further information that might help you solve the problem, pointing you to the computer science theory that addresses your problem, or telling you where you went wrong without providing a specific fix to your code.